# Batch file or any other way to open daily updated forum

Tags: batch-file, web, automation, forums

Final Edit: Sorry everyone, this is getting more harder by the day. Easy way, buy an android tablet, get chromecast, and just teach them how to stream. That's easy enough for them I have figured out. This is my answer.

edit: If the question is vague, just say it that it's vague, instead of bashing my english writing skills.

Anyways, here is the addition that some of you suggested:

Say you open up any forum, there are various posts by various authors, most likely every day a new post comes up. The daily soaps are uploaded in a similar forum. Every day is a new soap that's uploaded. Presently, I have to sit along side them and open each soap so they can view it. What I wish to achieve is a program of some sort that, after just one click, opens up my web browser, goes to today's date in that forum, and begins the video.

IF this can't be done, just tell me it can't be done, there would be no hard feelings.

---

I am wanting to open a forum website that has links to daily soaps and is updated with new episodes regularly.

I can do this on my own, that's no issue, the problem is that I have my grandparents living with me that do not know english or how to operate a computer. I have made a booklet of instructions, complete with photos and description in our native language as to what to press and stuff, but they still aren't able to open it on their own.

I want to reduce their dependance on me so I am hoping there is some sort of a way for me to write a program that can open a website forum that's updated with new links every day so that all they have to do is press on that file and sit back and relax the show.

I consider myself a novice in programming, but have extensive background in Excel VBA macros. As a matter of fact, stackoverflow has been my go-to resource for most of my queries!!
My engineering background has allowed me to learn new stuff pretty quickly.

So, I am hoping to get an amazing discussion going and hopefully a path forward as to what I should be doing if this kind of stuff is even possible.

Thanks everyone, I appreciate you all reading this and taking the time to respond...

Comment: On StackOverflow, people are able to ask specific questions about problems they're having. Have you tried anything yet? What language are you using? People will be much happier to help if you've tried something on your own.

This really isn't a programming question.

Comment: @Khalos - he's using batch, but I agree; for having so many words, this question is surprisingly empty, especially coming from somebody who claims to have used Stack Overflow so much in the past.

Comment: @Khalos I apologize for the vagueness, I am stuck on this problem. SO I do not know where to even begin, or what language to look at, or is this sort of thing even possible. I am not hoping for a code or anything here, just a guidance as to what to do. That's it.

Comment: Is this just `iexplore.exe http://www.foo.com/forum` ¿?¿

Comment: I think it is better to solve this rather complex problem with web scraping. When you need to extract URLs from a website where you possible even might need to login batchfiles are no good fit.

Comment: @Marged That seems like a workable solution, I will get on it... will keep this updated with pass or failures.

Answer (score 1):

This strikes me as the type of question that would have been asked already on this site, but for the life of me I cannot find anything to indicate that this is a duplicate question (unless you're trying to open multiple URLs in the same script).

The `start` command will open URLs with your default browser.

```
start "" "http://www.google.com"
```

Except replace Google's url with the one you want to open. The first set of empty quotes is just there because `start` considers the first set of quotes it encounters to be the window's title, so `start "http://www.google.com"` won't do anything except open a command prompt with that title.

It's also worth noting that if there is a `%` in your URL, you need to use two in your script (like `start "" "http://www.google.com/search?q=50%%+battery+life"`)

Comment: Okay... I shoulld have been more descriptive. Say you open up any forum, there are various posts by various authors, most likely every day a new post comes up. The daily soaps are uploaded in a similar forum. Every day is a new soap that's uploaded. Presently, I have to sit along side them and open each soap so they can view it. What I wish to achieve is a program of some sort that, after just one click, opens up my web browser, goes to today's date in that forum, and begins the video.

Comment: @curiously-curious - You should definitely add that to your question (and delete the four paragraphs that have nothing to do with your question while you're at it). Depending on what forum software the website is using, you might want to look into downloading an RSS reader instead.